# Upper back exercises to balance out chest workout

Tags: workout-routines, strength-training

I do a lot of chest exercises, and I am worried I am not doing enough upper back exercises to balance this out. Predominantly I am doing chair dips, bench press, dumbbell flys, and push ups to target my chest.

What types of exercises should I do for my upper back to balance out these gains in my chest?

Comment: For your bench press and dumbbell flys, are you doing them both flat bench? Any incline/decline work other than the dips?

Comment: @JohnP Press is on flat bench, flys are on incline.  The only other decline exercise I do is decline push ups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pulling exercises.

Chin-ups, pull-ups, bent-over barbell rows, Kroc (one-arm dumbbell) rows, and body rows are all fine choices for working the upper back as a way to balance out a surfeit of pushing exercises.

Comment: With regards to working the back, does it matter if it is an upright or bent over barbell row?

Comment: @Moses I meant bent-over. Upright rows might be useful too, but I've never tried them and am not sure.

Comment: Upright rows will emphasize your upper traps and deltoids (ie. your shoulders).

Comment: Like Dave L mentioned, pulling movements. Among his list of rows you could add seated rows on a cable machine.